# Updating body background-color in sapper

Tags: svelte, sapper

I want to update the body background-color depending on the page/route I am. So far I am on this :

```
//index.svelte
:global(body) {
      background-color:white;
}

//about.svelte
:global(body) {
      background-color:blue;
}
```

When I go from one to the other page, the color change but when I come back to the previous one then it doesn't work. Any idea ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your current setup, is that you're basically resetting what should be considered the global style on `body` when you move from `index` to `about`.

One option to apply your styles to the `body`: you could try adding a `<style>` element into each template's [svelte:head](https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_head) element.

Something like this:

```
// index.svelte
<svelte:head>
  <style>
    body {
      background: white;
    }
  </style>
</svelte:head>

// about.svelte
<svelte:head>
  <style>
    body {
      background: blue;
    }
  </style>
</svelte:head>
```

There's been [some discussion](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3105#issuecomment-622437031) about adding a `class:` directive to `<svelte:body>` for doing this sort of thing, so maybe this will be updated later.